# Trying to merge audio with video using ffmpeg

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg

I am using `ffmpeg` for merging audio and video. I download a 4 second long MP3 file trying to merge but not successful. i am also trying to merge silent audio. It works but the video become half of its original length. The following command works for silent audio but cuts the video:

```
String mergecmd1[]={"-i",output,"-f", "lavfi" ,"-i", "aevalsrc=0", " - 
shortest", "-y", output};
```

This is the command I have used for MP3 audio but it does not work:

```
   String cmd1[]={"-i", output ,"- 
   i","/storage/emulated/0/FestiveApp/Assets/audio.mp3" ,"-codec", "copy", 
   "-shortest", output};

         ffmpeg = FFmpeg.getInstance(Donts_Activity.this);
    try {

        ffmpeg.execute(command, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onStart() {
```

//                    Log.e("ffmpeg","Exaction Start");
                }

```
            @Override
            public void onProgress(String message) {}

            @Override
            public void onFailure(String message) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Log.e("ok",message);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String message) {
                new Sessionmanager(Donts_Activity.this).SetImageToVideoPath(output);

                Log.e("ok","success");


                progressDialog.dismiss();

                Intent intent=new Intent(Donts_Activity.this,MediaRecorderRecipe.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {

            }
        });
    } catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException e) {
        Log.e("ffmpeg",e.toString());
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
```

My first goal generate video with audio but video length does not be reduce or cut if i am using mp3 or silent ffmpeg audio command

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. If you want to avoid getting downvoted very rapidly, you should revise your text and make sure that the code is formatted properly. Also make sure that ordinary text is NOT formatted as code! Check your spelling, punctuation and capitalization. Spell things correctly. Write "I", not "i". I have tried to edit your code and text but you really need to do this yourself.

Comment: thanks  i will be very careful for next time

Comment: Again, "does not work" is not a useful or informative description of the actual error. You have not been receiving answers to your recent questions because you only say "does not work" or "wont work", but you did not show us any of the actual errors. Therefore, we do not know if the problem is with your code or with the ffmpeg command or both. Try to narrow it down before asking. Testing your unscripted ffmpeg command in a command line interface is a good way to do that. Provide the log from the ffmpeg command. If you don't know how then add `-report` option and it will generate a huge log.